# Ticks marks are moving upon changing the type of Chart

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I am using Highcharts in AngularJS.

My issue is that every time I change the type of graph, the tick marks are moving along the x-axis.

I don't want it to move along the x-axis.

I want it to be start from the origin.

Screenshots:

1. Before changing the type of graph

[image]

2. After changing the type of graph

[image]

Comment: can you provide your code sample for rendering updated charts

Comment: It was happening because of the size of column graph. I was changing graph type from line to column and column has some width.

Answer (score 0):

Set [`yAxis.min`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.min) = 0.

PS: Both screenshots are the same.

Comment: Would `startOnTick: true` also help in this regard?

Comment: yAxis.min doesn't working for me but `pointPlacement:"on"` is working. But it is giving unexpected result.

Comment: It was happening because of the size of column graph. I was changing graph type from line to column and column has some width and Highcharts was taking measures to plot the column and hence shifting the label.

Comment: Oh, sorry, now I see the difference between your images. That's correct, column-type series requires more space than line and this is expected behaviour. See solutions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923958/highchart-line-or-area-not-starting-at-the-left-point), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17179393/highcharts-why-is-there-extra-spacing-before-the-first-column-and-after-the-la) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41324956/highcharts-remove-space-before-first-bar-and-after-last).

Comment: I found the answer. It was happening becuase of the nature of column graph. The tick is placing exactly at the center of the column and the column is taking equal area in left and right direction of the tip. So to show it cleanly, highcharts is shifting the tick from the origin.